# Is it impossible for a finite human to commit a mortal sin by its very definition?

Tags: catholicism, mortal-sin

A mortal sin requires 3 things: grave matter, full knowledge, and deliberate consent.

As finite beings, we cannot fully know God--this is stated by the apophatic tradition which includes Aquinas and Dionysus the Areopagite. Thus, we cannot know with absolute certainty what God considers a grave matter. The Catholic Church has not put together an infallible list of grave matters.

Even if we were sure that God considered something a grave matter, we could not be absolutely sure that any specific act is an example of that grave matter. Stabbing someone in one instance is murder; in another, it is surgery. Is sex with a concubine adultery?

We cannot know all the subconscious drives or instincts which contribute to any of our decisions. We are not in absolute control of our actions. Much of our choice is based on unconscious survival instincts of which we are not aware inherited from our ancestors. Untreated PTSD can trigger violent acts.

We don't know how much systemic or cultural forces are contributing to our choice. For instance, stealing drugs when there is no national program to reduce prices might be a mitigating factor. I might not be aware of my racism because I'm living in a racist community.

We can't overcome our limited knowledge of God. We can't fully know the nature of any specific act. Psychology and social science show we are not in full control of any of our decisions. No amount of deliberation can overcome unconscious or cultural forces. We cannot, of our own will, overcome concupiscence.

Therefore, finite beings cannot fulfill the conditions for mortal sin. Right?

Comment: I am not Catholic and could not begin to address this excellent question from that perspective.  I do not know why there is a vote to close and I would hope that the voter would offer an explanation. +1

Comment: Your logic is flawed from the beginning. It doesn't follow that we cannot know what constitutes grave matter because we cannot fully know God.

Comment: I base that on the fact that there is no infallible list of grave matters. If it was possible to be known, then there would be a list. And even if something made the list, like adultery, it would be impossible to know whether the specific act we were committing was adultery.

Comment: We firmly believe and confess without reservation that there is only one true God, eternal infinite (immensus) and unchangeable, incomprehensible, almighty and ineffable (.)

Comment: The promptings of feelings and passions can also diminish the voluntary and free character of the offense, as can external pressures or pathological disorders.

Comment: 43 Admittedly, in speaking about God like this, our language is using human modes of expression; nevertheless it really does attain to God himself, though unable to express him in his infinite simplicity. Likewise, we must recall that "between Creator and creature no similitude can be expressed without implying an even greater dissimilitude";17 and that "concerning God, we cannot grasp what he is, but only what he is not, and how other beings stand in relation to him."18

Comment: 42 God transcends all creatures. We must therefore continually purify our language of everything in it that is limited, image-bound or imperfect, if we are not to confuse our image of God--"the inexpressible, the incomprehensible, the invisible, the ungraspable"--with our human representations.16 Our human words always fall short of the mystery of God.

Comment: The question shows a lack of research. Not only does Catholicism teach those 3 requirements for mortal sin, but teaches a) that there is revelation from God and b) the fallen nature of man.

Comment: "I base that on the fact that there is no infallible list of grave matters." Ever hear of the Ten Commandments?

Comment: @MikeBorden I agree that this is an excellent question, and wonder why the negative votes.

Comment: I'm surprised that you know Aquinas says you can't know God and yet don't seem familiar with Aquinas' understanding of mortal sin -- Hint: he definitely thinks it's possible to commit

Comment: "It is striking that the Church teaches definitively that certain human individuals have persevered in God’s grace and live now in glory with God forever in heaven, and that there is no equivalent teaching about individuals in hell. Think what we might about the state of Judas’s soul, or Hitler’s, or Stalin’s, or Nero’s, the Church not only fails to teach that they are damned, it positively invites us to pray for their salvation. “Lead all souls to heaven,” says the Fatima prayer, “especially those most in need of thy mercy.”   https://churchlifejournal.nd.edu/articles/is-hell-good-news/

Comment: "Psychology and social science show we are not in full control of any of our decisions." Says who? That's a vague claim at best and one I would doubt they all agree on.

Comment: I got that in Psych 101. It's a pretty standard belief of psychology. I'd be happy to look at the thought of any psychologist who suggests there are no unconscious forces at work in our decision-making process. Many psychologists say there is no free will at all--hence, no culpability.   https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2016/06/theres-no-such-thing-as-free-will/480750/

Comment: @Ashpenaz just because some psychologists deny free will doesn't mean Catholicism agrees. Secular psychology in many ways is in conflict on fundamental principles with Catholicism.

Answer (score 5):

**Fallible humans can definitely fulfil the conditions to commit a mortal sin.**

Let's take a really clear cut case. Let's say I embezzled some money from my employer. A co-worker discovers this and tells me they will go to the police. Before they can do this I put a gun to their head and kill them.

Let's look at the conditions:

1. **Grave matter.** It is clear from the teachings of the church that killing someone is a grave matter. It ought to be obvious to anyone that is the case, even without the church's teaching. There is no reasonable way I can claim i thought killing someone was not "grave".
2. **Full knowledge**. I am aware of the pertinent facts. I know that when I pull the trigger they will die. I know that they are a human. I have no reason to think that killing them is justified. Even if I don't have omniscient knowledge of the circumstances I have enough knowledge to know that what I do is wrong.
3. **Deliberate consent.** Nothing is forcing me to kill this person. Nobody has misled me into thinking that I ought to kill this person. Whatever pressures or temptations I have to kill someone I have the choice to do it or not, and if I do it with thought then I give my *deliberate consent*.

Even if it is true that there are "subconscious urges" or anything else that "contribute" to me *wanting* to kill this person, if I actually have the choice to do it or not then the decision is mine and that amounts to deliberate consent.

If I am suffering from something like a mental disorder that effectively removes freedom of choice from me that it may be true that I have not sinned. Mitigating factors that make it hard for me to resist sinning might also reduce the perceived severity of an offence. But those mitigating factors may or may not be there, and short of a disorder everybody has a choice in what they do.

To answer the question a posed: "**Yes it is absolutely possible for a person to commit a mortal sin."**

Comment: What you are describing is the act of a sociopath, and their mental disorder renders them inculpable. The only reason I would want to kill a random stranger would be because I'm insane--which is a mitigating factor. No sane person in an unimpeded relationship with God would want to randomly kill another human being. If I was fully in communion with God, that would never occur to me. Subconscious forces to which I do not have conscious access, and which therefore aren't deliberate, such as the impact of an earlier trauma, or a personality disorder, are giving me the desire to kill.

Comment: To be clear--I am not say we don't sin. I am saying there are no mortal sins. All sins are venial. Yes, we can know something is wrong and make the choice to do it--but there are always mitigating factors which prevent our sins from being mortal. We commit venial sin when we "disobey the moral law in a grave matter, but without full knowledge or without complete consent." And I am arguing there is never full knowledge or complete consent. And also, we can't know for sure what God considers a grave matter.

Comment: I've been trying to think of an example of someone who matches your description. Not Hitler--he likely had a narcissistic personality disorder which rendered him inculpable. It doesn't make his acts less evil--he'll be in Purgatory a long time. Not Judas--he thought he was saving the Jewish nation from a false prophet. Not Satan--a finite being who believed he would achieve happiness by defying God, for which he was mistaken and ignorant. When, after we committed the most evil act ever, Jesus from the cross said, "Forgive them for they know not what they do," He declared all sins venial.

Comment: @Ashpenez You are falling into a fallacy trap. Sociopathy is NOT a reason to be "not guilty" of a crime, either in the law or morally. The so-called "insanity" defense is much more limited than people think. It is not enough to be "insane" in the commonly-used sense. You either have to be delusional enough that you did not know what you were doing, or in a state where you did not know right from wrong. "Narcissistic personality disorder" would not of itself be a defense in the case you are trying to put together.

Comment: If you are looking for a debate on this, please don't have it here. I have created a chat room if you want to follow up: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135982/is-it-impossible-for-a-finite-human-to-commit-a-mortal-sin-by-its-very-definition

Comment: @Ashpenaz your supposition that there are no mortal sins is erroneous at best or else philosophically flawed. This answer correctly explains to a sufficient degree what constitutes a mortal sin.

Answer (score 3):

The thesis here is that there is no sin where the sin is known to be grave and fully consented to. Because of this, the question is how can one mortally sin

The can be easily disproved using the Catholic Church's requirement to attend Mass on Sundays and obligatory Holy Days as an example. Here, the Church has bound the faithful to such obligation under pain of mortal sin. As long as a Catholic thinks that the Church has that power on Earth, given by Christ, then it follows that this constitutes grave matter. Furthermore, it is evident that we can know that this constitutes grave matter, as the preceding argument proves it.

All that remains is the ability to fully consent, and it is manifestly evident that as long as the concept of consent is useful, one can consent to missing Mass on one of these obligatory days. If one cannot fully consent because of some unknowable subconscious processes, then the idea of consent used in so many other places becomes incoherent. In business contracts, in criminal law, in divorce courts, etc. The only way to hold that one cannot consent to skipping mass is to say that no one can ever really consent to anything.

QED, at least with this one particular sin, it is possible to sin mortally.

Answer (score 1):

I've only read half the introduction to Peter Kreeft's [Socratic Logic](https://www.christianbook.com/socratic-logic-3-1-edition/peter-kreeft/9781587318085/pd/00083X?kw=1241348712202415&mt=b&dv=c&event=PPCSRC&p=1215904&msclkid=b3842f9f4aca1ede18e74de5c8828f84&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Dynamic%20Search%20Ads&utm_term=%2Fpd%2F&utm_content=DSA%20detail%20pages) so bear with me, I'm finally beginning to understand the distinction between the human logic of Aristotle and the symbolic logic of the computer that I'm acquainted with as a programmer.

Aristotelian logic accepts the qualifiers as theorems and if they're true - whatever they add up to is true. The Church admits them theorems like: "all men are cads" and "some sins are worse than others" and "people have freewill" and "some consciences are well formed"

These form the argument "because all men are cads they may want to commit sins and because they have free will they may choose to commit those sins and because some sins are worse than others, they may be classified as mortal sins and because a persons conscience can be well formed they can objectively discern that they committed a mortal sin;  therefore it is possible for a person to commit a mortal sin."

What I'm not sure that it is possible for a person to do is to be free from an attachment to sin (a pre-requisite for a plenary indulgence) but I'd like to think we can try and God will respect our efforts, finite as they may be.